# Check if WebSphere MQ is in Native Mode or JMS Mode

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I'm trying to figure out how to check what mode one of my IBM WebSphere MQ installations is running in.

In particular, I need to find out if this particular installation is running in Native Mode or JMS Mode.

I thought maybe I could find an answer using one of the provided IBM MQ CLI commands found [HERE](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083880_.htm?lang=en), but none of them seem to tell you what mode the installation is running in, or even how to change the mode.

Does anyone have any advice or guidance on how to detect what mode my installation is running in?

Comment: I am confused with what you mean by "Native Mode" or "JMS Mode"?  Are you referring to the transport mode used by a client application to connect to a queue manager (CLIENT being TCP/IP and BINDINGS being native shares memory)?

Comment: Ah, forgive my ignorance.  I am extremely new to MQ.  I see now.  An application uses either the native client or a JMS client in order to connect to MQ.  So I'll just need to figure out which client this application is using.  Thanks for helping me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client may use the JMS client OR the native client to connect to WMQ.

The server always runs in the same mode - and can handle both native and JMS.

Answer (score 2):

To figure out which type of client you have connecting into a queue manager, i.e. a native 'C' client or a JMS client, you can use the following command while the client application is running:-

```
DISPLAY CHSTATUS(*) RPRODUCT
```

The different types of clients have different values in `RPRODUCT`. The native 'C' client will show `MQCC` and JMS will show `MQJM`.

**Reference**

[DISPLAY CHSTATUS - Look for attribute RPRODUCT for full set of values](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q109455_.htm)

[IBM MQ Little Gem post on RPRODUCT and RVERSION](https://www.imwuc.org/blog/ibm-mq-little-gem-2-rproduct-and-rversion)